# Jquery datepicker is not hiding after selecting date

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-datepicker

I use Jquery datepicker on my partial view. After selecting date from datepicker it does not close or hide. The datepicker pop up window is still open on the page

Comment: please share some code

Comment: @tereško None of these [suggested edits](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/28192963/3) should have been approved as no attempt has been made to improve the question so it's even remotely readable. See comment in [Review Queue](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6874013)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add autoClose : true in your configuration :

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({ autoClose: true});
```

Comment: Its not working vincent. If I select date from datepicker the pop up still exist there. I am working on IE 11

Comment: @ManishPandey. Did you solve this issue? I am also facing the same in IE 11 but working fine in Chrome. Please post your answer if it got resolved by any piece of code